# Print Dialog Box tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, dialog, box

I am trying to make notepad with Tkinter. But I don't know how to make printer dialog box so How do I make a printer dialog box with `Tkinter` in python?

Comment: `Tkinter` ? `Tkinter` is for python 2.x for 3.x its `tkinter` anyway the answer below sums your problem up

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you are looking for [here](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html#tkinter-standard-dialog-boxes)

Here is an example from the docs:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

answer = messagebox.askokcancel("Question","Do you want to open this file?")
answer = messagebox.askretrycancel("Question", "Do you want to try that again?")
answer = messagebox.askyesno("Question","Do you like Python?")
answer = messagebox.askyesnocancel("Question", "Continue playing?")
```

Comment: Weird enough, the OP mentioned about `Tkinter` could he be using python 2.x